A reliable way to check if a method has been wrapped with a decorator from within it
In python 3.7 or higher.
I have the following class:
def dec(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("wrapped")
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class A:
    @dec()
    def f1(self):
        print(is_wrapped())

    def f2(self):
        print(is_wrapped())

I want A().f1() to print True and A().f2() to print False.
I created the following code for is_wrapped:
def is_wrapped():
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    for v in frame.f_back.f_locals.values():
        if hasattr(v, '__code__') and v.__code__ is frame.f_code:
            return True

    return False

While this seems to work it can fail if the caller of f2 has a local variable that contains f2 but does not decorate it.
For my specific case you can assume the following.

The is_wrapped function is called directly from the function in a way that inspect.currentframe().f_back is the method that called it (i.e, f1 or f2)

The is_wrapped function cannot get any arguments.

the decorator can be implemented in any way as long as it uses functool.wraps for the wrapped function.


Is there any more reliable way to achieve this?

print([is_wrapped() for _ in range(2)]) (python 3.11 and below, changed in 3.12) or print((lambda: is_wrapped())()) inside a decorated method are obvious failure cases.

@STerliakov You can assume is_wrapped is called directly from within a method of a class not a function/lambda/iterator defined in it. I was more worried about a case the decorator is built in such a way that f1 is not the last element in f_locals (if thats possible).

Yes, that's possible as well (def dec(method): x = 1 @functools.wraps(method) def w(*args, **kw): x; return method(*args, **kw) return w), you cannot expect that the method will be last entry of locals in any frame.

@STerliakov even in your case it's still the last element, try it.

@STerliakov I've tried to add a lot of variables in their but but it always seems to work that it puts the method f1 as the last element (I have no idea why)

No, it is not: https://python-fiddle.com/saved/kDEcaWkLnJixgzZYpsYg

@STerliakov You are right I had a bug when I tested it. I'm editing the question.

Now fails with a more obscure case - but you may declare it rare enough and just document. https://python-fiddle.com/saved/uKSJMi6DoaisJkUWqumq

Yeah I know it fails in this case, if I won't find any way to solve it I'll just document it.

I have revisited this question since my last comment, and here's a probably better way: instead of looking for a local variable with same __code__ as frame's code, let's look for something that has __wrapped__ satisfying that condition.
Why is this better? Since you say that functools.wraps is a requirement for decorator, we can be sure that a decorator must have some local with __wrapped__ - that's the function built inside. So now we're looking for the following: "traversing from current frame, can the grandparent be a function definition that's called now?"
So, if current frame is the one inside is_wrapped, we traverse one back to the original method (f1). This assumes that decorator does actually call the decorated function, which makes sense given functools.wraps requirement. If there are no previous frame, we're at some wrong place, probably is_wrapped shouldn't even be called from that. Otherwise, go a step further: we're now in function built inside the decorator.
So the sketch of a modified version may look like this:
import gc

def is_wrapped():
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    if frame is None:
        raise RuntimeError("No call frame found")
    orig_code = frame.f_code  # Looking for this original definition
    if frame.f_back is None:
        return False
    deco_code = frame.f_back.f_code
    
    for o in gc.get_referrers(frame.f_back.f_code):
        if getattr(o, '__code__', None) is deco_code and hasattr(o, '__wrapped__'):
            return getattr(o.__wrapped__, '__code__', None) is orig_code 
            
    return False

It passes all "testcases" from your question and comments, works for "deep" decorators that accept parameters, but is still breakable - for example, if a decorator-created function does not call the original code, you're out of luck. But it's something less trivial than simply referencing the method in enclosing scope, isn't it?
Credits for gc approach of retrieving the actual function go to @MikeHordecki.
Use at your own risk and test thoroughly. Also note that

Warning: Care must be taken when using objects returned by get_referrers() because some of them could still be under construction and hence in a temporarily invalid state. Avoid using get_referrers() for any purpose other than debugging.


I have solved a similar issue previously by marking the decorated function with an attribute:
import functools


def dec(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("wrapped")
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper._is_wrapped = True  # Mark the wrapper function
    return wrapper


class A:
    @dec
    def f1(self):
        print(is_wrapped(self.f1))

    def f2(self):
        print(is_wrapped(self.f2))


def is_wrapped(method):
    if method and hasattr(method, '_is_wrapped'):
        return True
    return False


a = A()
a.f1()  # Prints "True" (and "wrapped", per the wrapper)
a.f2()  # Prints "False"

By explicitly marking the wrapped functions with an _is_wrapped attribute we can simply test for its presence. This does require us to edit the decorator, but I feel this approach is more robust than testing for any old decorator.

Yeah, I have also tried plugging my question to chatgpt and got your exact answer. First of all since we use functool wraps wrapper already contains attribute __ wrapped __ so no need for _is_wrapped second of all I don't want to pass self.f1 to the is_wrapped method.

I wrote the answer myself, and confirmed all code I wrote worked as intended prior to posting the answer. I'm aware __wrapped__ is available, but as mentioned above, and in my previous implementations, I have found it more useful to test for a specific decorator as opposed to a general one. On topic of the question, why do you not wish to pass the method you intend to test to the is_wrapped() function? I might suggest passing dir(self.f1) instead, but without understanding your broader intent, I reckon this too is not an option for you.

Yeah sorry for the chatgpt statement, it can be just a coincidence its just weird that I got the exact same code (not that there is anything wrong with using chatgpt in your answer, useful tool after all). It's actually very long to explain it's for a very specific use case in a library I create for my self for fun that implement public private protected and static keywords for python similar to cpp. It works well except when private methods are being decorated and I didn't find any way I think is completely reliable to solve it.
